# What is better for chilled cheesecake - pectin or gelatin?

Tags: gelatin, cheesecake, jelly, pectin

I am currently doing my food technology GCSE coursework and need a Lemon Cheesecake recipe for next week.

I was planning on having an enriched shortcrust base, with a *chilled* lemon cheesecake filling. It will also have raspberry coulis and meringue peaks as a garnish.

I saw a picture on Instagram of a cheesecake with clear, strawberry jelly (I don't know if it was *jello* [American word for 'jelly' in British English], or *jelly* [a clear conserve]). I want to know what it was, 'jello' or 'jelly' because jelly requires pectin (thus heat) to set but jello just requires gelatin.

What is my best course of action, because in my eyes, if I make jelly, it would set too quickly, therefore I would need to pour it onto the cheesecake whilst it's hot, thus melting the filling; but jello wouldn't need any heat?

Comment: When you say "chilled" you mean a recipe with a filling that is never baked? If that's the case, you might consider looking for the key-words "no-bake cheesecake". Standard cheesecakes are always baked (as far as I know, in the US).

Comment: Also, if you can find the image again, you can add it to your question. It might be easier for us to identify that way.

Comment: Indeed, the source seems very relevant here, since you're asking about a US vs UK English thing.

Comment: I had experimented w/ what temperatures I could pour gelatin and still have it be clear.  See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/54070/67 .  What you might be able to do is pour a disk of gelatin, let it cool, then unmold it and set it on top of the cheesecake.  If you have to, reserve some to place down as a thickened gel first, then add the disk on top.  It might also be possible for a pectin-based gel to cook at the same time as the cheesecake (I think gelatin loses its gelling power if held near boiling for too long, if I remember correctly)

Comment: It may have been strawberry glaze you saw in the photo. It is made with a starch thickener, generally corn starch, and either flavored gelatin or fruit/juice.

Comment: You also have agar agar, guar gum, locust bean gum, xanthan gum, gellan gum and carrageenan. Depending on the texture and clarity you require. Some of these require very little or no heat to gel and can just be poured over the cheesecake after.

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers. I guess I'll use gelatin because it's clear and sets slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the jelly is something like the brand Oetker which comes clear or fruit-flavoured. It is indeed poured warm; cheesecake will survive if it's a cm or less layer.

Alternatively, boil up some apricot jam (or strawberry), take off heat a few minutes and sieve through a tea strainer over cheesecake. 
Keep stirring the pot if you are slow.