# Food science of thickeners such as starches and gelatins

Tags: food-science

What types of recipes are best to  thicken using gelatin and which are best to thicken using starches, such as corn starch or potato starch.

Comment: something like this? 
http://www.edinformatics.com/math_science/science_of_cooking/food_thickening_agents.htm

Comment: It's not just a factor of what's being thickened, but other preparations (some are thermo-reversable, some aren't.  Some have a limited time range (will become hard and/or 'weep' over time.  Some will break if frozen.  I know that I researched the topic quite a bit when I was working on https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/41369/67 , but I have no idea where I put those notes (temp ranges, acidity ranges, notes of problems (eg, one didn't work well w/ dairy)