# Homemade powdered jello recipe

Tags: dessert, gelatin

I am allergic to the corn starch that is often found in the ready made brands. I would like to be able to make some powdered jello up for when I want to make a quick jello. With my illnesses, at times, I am unable to cook the jello in the recipes that I have found in my searches. Does anyone have a recipe for the amounts of dried fruit juice, unflavored gelatin, and a sweetener that can be made ahead of time and then mixed with boiling water as though it was a store bought brand? `

Comment: I am surprised about the corn starch thing, Jell O (the one I googled) does not list that in the ingredients lists ?

Comment: Does it really have to be a 100% powdered mix?  I'd think that a good blend of superfine sugar, unflavored gelatin, and citric acid could then be modified by whatever flavoring you wanted to add.

Comment: I should also mention -- I don't know if the powdered mixes do something to keep the gelatin from clumping when pouring in boiling water.  I'd probably add some of the water first to wet down the whole thing and let the gelatin hydrate (bloom), then add the rest as boiling water to melt it.  (or possibly part of the remaining as boiling, make sure it's all disolved, then the rest as cold water so it'll set faster)

Comment: I wonder what you mean by "I am unable to cook the jello in the recipes that I have found in my searches". The basic form is to cook up fruit juice with unflavored gelatine, which is about the same effort as cooking up jello powder with water. Or do you mean that you found more complicated recipes, or are you trying to imitate some kind of instant-puddding product (no heating)? Could you please give examples for the recipes which are too complex, and say what preparation process is OK for you?

Answer (score 1):

Some quick digging brought up [a recipe for gluten-free jello](https://glutenfreeonashoestring.com/easy-homemade-jello-gelatin/) that used a ratio of :

- 1TB gelatin
- 3-5TB granulated sugar
- 2c. fruit juice

There are lots of similar ones out there ... some call for more gelatin if they're planning on putting it in a mold (1TB/cup) or making squares you can hold (1.5TB/cup), and some replace part of the juice with a fruit puree.

The exact amount of sugar is going to depend on how sweet the flavoring is, so you might need to play with this one a bit to experiment.  And you may need some citric acid (or a citrus fruit powder) to balance out overly sweet flavorings.

I would also be careful about both how I stored and hydrated the mixture.  Sugar will absorb moisture out of the air, which might result in the mix clumping together before you can use it.  I'd try to put it into pre-measured containers that have little headroom, or where the air can be removed (eg, zip-top bags).

For hydrating, you'd want to mix it into maybe 1/8 of the total liquid and let it sit to hydrate.  If you see any powdery lumps, break those up before you add any hot water.  You could then add 3/8 of the water as boiling and stir to dissolve it completely, then add the remaining 1/2 as cold water to cool it down.

I'm sorry I couldn't be more specific about this.  My attempts at making gelatin [used liquid flavorings](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/41369/67).